# How to use MySQL LIKE

Tags: mysql, sql-like

I cannot get the LIKE to work in mysql on a WHERE clause

This what I need to find in a string `"blog_optin";s:1:"1";`

Here are the things I tried:

`WHERE meta_value LIKE "%\"blog_optin\";s:1:\"1\";%"`

`WHERE meta_value LIKE %"\"blog_optin\";s:1:\"1\";"%`

Comment: Looks like serialized PHP objects to me.

Comment: It's a wordpress meta_value field @OllieJones

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try that:

```
 WHERE meta_value LIKE '%"blog_optin";s:1:"1";%'
```

[**DEMO**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ab4e81/1)

Comment: no, I can't split it because the whole string represents what I am looking for

Comment: i dont know this if it works or not , but give it a try.

Comment: and please enable display errors to see what error instead of blank page

Comment: that's the same thing I tried as my first attempt in my OQ

Comment: I did enable errors but the page filled with all the Wordpress warnings and nothing related to my query. it is as if the query returned nothing

Comment: I think @OllieJones may have been on to something in his comment in the OQ -- now I need to figure out how to unserialize the string

Comment: Ok, I tried your fiddle and added `(4, 'a:2:{s:13:"company_optin";s:1:"1";s:10:"blog_optin";s:1:"1";}')` I got an error building schema {bw the value here is identical to the entire string in the table column}